# Add more than a field in selectfield displayvalue (Sencha Touch 2)

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have the following select field :

```
{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    name: 'sourcecurrency',
    label: 'Source Currency',
    valueField: 'name',
    displayField: '{name} - {description}',
    store: 'Countries',
    placeHolder: 'Select your source currency'
},
```

The data is returning two fields 'name' and 'description'; I want to display the two fields in the select area, setting the displayField as shown works but i still have the '{}' surrounding them.

Must be really damn stupid but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct way of showing more than one field in `selectfield's` `displayField`.

So, you will need to create an extension based on the `selectfield`.

Comment: That's what i thought; where to get started ?

Comment: You can start working by having a look at this .. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?147676-Sencha-Touch-Custom-Picker-Form-Field

Comment: Wow! Don't you have an 'beginner' example ? ;)

Comment: for a beginner is quite hard to understand

Answer (score 1):

I know its old, but heres another way to go about it for completeness:

Create a field like DisplayName in your model and have that be whatever combination of fields and information you want the display.

Then just have displayField: '{displayName}'

Creating a custom field is more efficient, but this is easier.  Just depends on what you need to display and how efficient you need your app to be and how much time you want to invest in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone you can just ovveride getTabletPicker or getPhonePicker (Tested in sencha 6).

For example in getTabletPicker all you need to change is line

```
 itemTpl: '<span class="x-list-label">{' + me.getDisplayField() + ':htmlEncode}</span>',
```

to something else like

```
  itemTpl : me.getTpl()
```

so your selectfield would be

```
        xtype        : 'selectfield',
        displayField : 'YOURDISPLAY',
        valueField   : 'YOURVALUE',            
        tpl          : new Ext.XTemplate(
                        '<tpl for=".">',
                            '{YOURDISPLAY}',
                            '{YOURDISPLAY2}',
                            '{YOURDISPLAY3}',
                        '</tpl>'
                       )
```